# Deselecting above checkboxes (a "none of above" option)

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am working on this demo. How I can fix the code for last checkbox in a way to deselect all of above checkboxes when check and do nothing on un-check states?

```
<input id="selectAll" type="checkbox" name="slectAll">
<label for="selectAll">Yes, Select All</label>
<fieldset id="group_1">
   <input type="checkbox" name="numbers[]" value="0" />Item 1<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="numbers[]" value="1" />Item 2<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="numbers[]" value="2" />Item 3<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="numbers[]" value="3" />Item 4<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="numbers[]" value="4" />Item 5<br />
</fieldset>
<input id="planB" type="checkbox" name="planB">
<label for="planB">I am not Sure</label>

<script>
$(function() {
  var $all = $('input:checkbox[name=slectAll]').change(function() {
    $checks.prop("checked", this.checked);
  });

  var $checks = $('#group_1 :checkbox').change(function() {
    $all.prop("checked", $checks.not(':checked').length == 0);
  });

  var $none = $('input:checkbox[name=planB]').change(function() {
    $checks.prop("checked", this.checked);
  });    

 });    
</script>
```

Comment: But what should happen if you check either `all` of any of the `numbers[]` check boxes after checking `planB`

Comment: what I would I like to do is deselecting the `planB` if any of all or `numbers[]` been selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for the checked status

```js
$(function() {
  var $all = $('input:checkbox[name=slectAll]').change(function() {
    $checks.prop("checked", this.checked);
    $none.prop('checked', false);
  });

  var $checks = $('#group_1 :checkbox').change(function() {
    $all.prop("checked", $checks.not(':checked').length == 0);
    $none.prop('checked', false);
  });

  var $none = $('input:checkbox[name=planB]').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $checks.add($all).prop("checked", false);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="selectAll" type="checkbox" name="slectAll"/>
<label for="selectAll">Yes, Select All</label>
<fieldset id="group_1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="numbers[]" value="0" />Item 1<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="numbers[]" value="1" />Item 2<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="numbers[]" value="2" />Item 3<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="numbers[]" value="3" />Item 4<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="numbers[]" value="4" />Item 5<br />
</fieldset>
<input id="planB" type="checkbox" name="planB"/>
<label for="planB">I am not Sure</label>
```

Comment: Thanks Arun but there is a minor issue here! as if you select planB and again select one of items or select all planB still is checked!